# Python nlst only files that older than 2 two days

Tags: python, ftps

I use `nlst` in Python to get a list of the FTP-folders? How can I get only folders that are older than 2 days?
For example what I use at the moment to get the full folderlist:

```
ftps = FTP_TLS()
ftps.set_pasv(True)
ftps.connect(ftp_server, ftp_port)
ftps.login(ftp_username, ftp_userpass)
ftps.prot_p()
items = ftps.nlst('-tr /folder')

for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Comment: I would recommend producing a [minimal reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or, to the least, report the code you are using at the moment.

Comment: I have add an example!